# Difference in the event loop phases between node.js and v8 in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, event-loop

I understand about the event loop in node.js thanks to many resources in the web (e.g. https://jsblog.insiderattack.net/timers-immediates-and-process-nexttick-nodejs-event-loop-part-2-2c53fd511bb3). So I know something already about node.js and the libuv.

However, what does the event loop phases look like in browser situation for 'normal' js use case in classic web application scenario? Says the event loop in Chrome with V8?